# How are quantum error-correction conditions in Nielsen and Chuang implemented in practice?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, error-correction, nielsen-and-chuang

Quantum error-correction conditions in Nielsen and Chuang, 10th-anniversary edition (Theorem 10.1) state that the error operation $\mathcal{E}$ with operation elements $\{E_i\}$ is correctable if and only if $PE^\dagger_iE_jP=\alpha_{ij}P$, where $P$ is a projector onto the code space $C$ and $\alpha$ is a Hermitian matrix. Here $C$ is understood as a subspace of the full Hilbert space that contains the states that need to be protected against noise.
The proof of the theorem relies on properties of the projection operator $P$ among other things.

The basic example that illustrates how error correction works uses either the repetition code or the Shor code.In the repetition code, the original 1 qubit state (that needs to be protected) $|\psi\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ is mapped into $a|000\rangle+b|111\rangle$. Then bit-flip error occurs on one of the 3 qubits and it is demonstrated how this bit-flip can be corrected. If the bit-flip operation is $\mathcal{E}$, then encoding of the original state must be $P$, ie projection of the full Hilbert space onto the code space, but neither repetition code, nor Shor code is a projection operator, they're just combinations of standard unitary gates.

I'm trying to understand how theorem 10.1 is related to the actual error-correction codes, and how is projection operators required by Theorem 10.1 implemented in practice.

Answer (score 2):

A quantum error correcting code always defines a *codespace*, that is a subspace of the Hilbert space on $n$ qubits. For example the 3-qubit bitflip code's codespace is that spanned by the vectors $|000\rangle$ and $|111\rangle$.

Given a QEC with a set of basis vectors $|c_i\rangle$ its projector is just given by
$$
P = \sum_i |c_i\rangle\langle c_i|
$$
So $P = |000\rangle\langle 000| + |111\rangle\langle 111|$ for the bitflip code.

An error $E$ has the effect of transforming the codespace within the larger Hilbert space. All theorem 10.1 is saying is that for a set of errors $E_i$ to be correctable, the corresponding transformed codespaces must not overlap. If they did overlap, then it would not be possible to tell which error had moved a codeword out of the original codespace, and therefore not possible to correct it.

Comment: Thank you, it does make sense to me, but if you look at the implementation of the 3-qubit bit flip example, the encoding of the original state (=projection onto the codespace?) is just a repetition of the state of the original qubit (i.e. CNOT(q0,q1)CNOT(q0,q2)) which if I am not mistaken can be expressed as $C = |0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I\otimes I + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes X\otimes X$, and as such $C$ is not a projection operator $P$. That's what I'm trying to understand how does the implementation of the bit flip error correction correspond to the condition of Theorem 10.1.

Comment: The theorem doesn't say anything about implementations, it's just a mathematical condition for a code to be able to correct a set of errors. For the 3-bit repetition code it will tell you the set of all single-qubit bitflip errors is correctable. Or that the set of all two-qubit bitflip errors is correctable. But a set containing both $X_1$ and $X_2 X_3$ is not. Once you know a set of errors is correctable, you can then figure out how to actually correct them.

Comment: It doesn't say about implementation, but the sufficiency of the condition is proved by constructing explicit error-correction operation $\mathcal{R}(\sigma)=\sum_kU^\dagger_kP_k\sigma P_kU_k$. It's my understanding that as any other quantum operation $\mathcal{R}$ has some corresponding system-environment interaction model and that model can be implemented as a quantum circuit. Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: No your assumption is not incorrect, this is known as the [dilation theorem](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/church-larger-hilbert-space). What is incorrect is the statement in your original question that "neither repetition code, nor Shor code is a projection operator, they're just combinations of standard unitary gates". All QECs have a corresponding projector defined as above.

Answer (score 0):

To correct errors using an error-correction you do measurements (of an ancilla or of the data qubits), which are projections.